# Count multiple patterns using the str_count function in R

Tags: r, string, count

Fairly new to R and struggling a bit with using the `string_count` function to detect multiple words that are unknown and are contained within a separate vector.

Now, I know how to detect a single instance of a pattern using the following code:

```
str_count(mydf$string, "Apples")
```

What I want to do is detect multiple words (e.g. "Apples", "Pears", "Oranges" etc) from a vector that is in itself created from another data frame (e.g. by using `Uniques<-unique(mydf1$words)`).

The key thing here is that the words that appear in `mydf1$words` are entirely dependent on what data has been uploaded to R in the first place, as this will change from data set to data set.

The answer is probably pretty straight forward but for the life of me I cant seem to work it out!

Comment: `table(mydf$string)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you mean the `str_count` function in the stringr package?

If so, it uses regular expressions and in the pattern for regular expressions the `|` character means "or", so `str_count(mydf$string, 'apple|pear')` will count the occurrences of "apple" or "pear" to give a total count.  The string with the `|` characters can be constructed with `paste`, try:

```
str_count(mydf$string, paste(Uniques, collapse='|'))
```

You can see the string that is constructed by `paste` by just running that part of the code.  Note that if you construct a pattern with a lot of options then it may run very slowly.  Another option would be to split the 1st string into individual words and compare the vector of words with the vector of options using the `%in%` operator (then count the TRUE's).

Comment: Thats it! thats exactly what I was after - thanks so much for answering. I'm still getting to grips with R and didn't know about the | character at all: so simple!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the expected result.  Perhaps:

```
 library(stringr)
 sapply(unique(vec1), function(x) str_count(vec1,x))
 #       Apples Pears Oranges
 #[1,]      1     0       0
 #[2,]      0     1       0
 #[3,]      0     0       1
 #[4,]      1     0       0
 #[5,]      1     0       0
 #[6,]      0     1       0
```

#### data

```
  vec1 <- c("Apples","Pears","Oranges","Apples","Apples","Pears")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are counting occurrences in a character vector created by unique() the count should be 1 for everything ;) Try using the table() function on your vector.

```
table(c("Apples","Pears","Oranges","Apples","Apples","Pears"))[["Apples"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `%in%` a try

```
x <- c("Apples","Pears","Oranges","Apples","Apples","Pears")
sum(x %in% "Apples")
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think answer from @akrun is good and I did some modification to save all results in a data frame.

```
library(stringr)
 
vec1 <- c("Apples","Pears","Oranges","Apples","Apples","Pears")

sapply(vec1, function(x) str_count(mydf$string,x))

Result<-data.frame(Group=sapply(unique(vec1), function(x) sum(str_count(mydf$string,x))))
Result
```

Then, we can use the total result to get a pie plot or similar visualization.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what you're after than this should do it. You will firstly need to create a single string of all the words into a single string using the `paste` command and the argument `collapse`.

```
library(stringr)
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")
fruit_together <- paste(fruit, collapse=" ")
fruit_together
```

Now you can use the newly merged string to see how many instances occur.

```
str_count(fruit_together, "apple")
```