# Extracting multiple conditions using stringr (r)

Tags: r, string, stringr

I am trying to extract a region of interest variable from a series of strings. There are multiple different regions of interest that I am trying to extract and put them all into one variable "ROI". However, when I do this, I get a corrupt dataframe that I am unable to export. Is there a string function that can handle extracting multiple "or" statements?

Thank you and please let me know if I can provide further information.

```
V2_MeanConcentration_LongFormat <- Visit2_concentration_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("ID"),  names_to = "Name", values_to = "Values") %>% 
  mutate(Condition = str_extract(Name, regex("ThreatAngryFearful|Happy")),
         Chromophore = str_extract(Name, regex("HbO|HHb", ignore_case = TRUE)),
         Hemisphere = str_extract(Name, regex("Left|Right", ignore_case = TRUE)),
        ROI = str_extract(Name, regex("MPFC|STC|DLPFC|IFC|Parietal", ignore_case = TRUE))%>%  ##This is not working ###
           as.data.frame((c("ID", "Condition", "Chromophore","Hemisphere", "ROI", "Name", "Values"))))
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: I find your last expression as `stri_extract` instead of `str_extract` and it is a stringi function where the `regex` would be `regex = ` instead of `regex(`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. Here is the error message Warning message:
In as.data.frame.vector(x, ..., nm = nm) :
  'row.names' is not a character vector of length 2736 -- omitting it. Will be an error!

Comment: When I tried this line - ROI = str_extract(Name, regex="MPFC|STC|DLPFC|IFC|Parietal", ignore_case = TRUE) - I got this error: Error in str_extract(Name, regex = "MPFC|STC|DLPFC|IFC|Parietal", ignore_case = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (regex = "MPFC|STC|DLPFC|IFC|Parietal", ignore_case = TRUE). Please let me know if I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please update your post with a small reproducible example so that others can test it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I had the same question for the `str_count`  function from the [stringr package](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/). `str_extract` belongs to the same package. As Akrun pointed out, there are different R packages for natural language processing.

Borrowing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125474/count-multiple-patterns-using-the-str-count-function-in-r) multiple patterns can be combined with the OR sign  --> `|`  . A solution would be:

```
newVar <- str_extract(DF$var, 'pattern1 | pattern2 | pattern3')
```

In your case the trouble arises because of the use of [`regex()` function](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) which belongs to the `stringi`package.
[`regex()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html) is only necessary for case insensitive searches and other complex searches.

Not knowing more about the data and what you need to achieve it is hard to help.