# How to count row numbers which contains different specific strings or characters simutaneously

Tags: r, string, sum

I find two better methods to count row numbers by specifics strings in one column.

One `is str_count from stringr`

Another one is `grepl`

I know how to count row numbers by scripts in each time but only get one resutls which contain specific strings.

**But I want to know how to count rows which contain different specific strings simutaneously.**

For example:

```
q.data<-data.frame(number=1:3, string=c("great_utr_great", "ma_DISTAL_gic", "n_LONG_ot"))
q.data<-q.data[rep(1:NROW(q.data), 3000),]


sum(str_count(q.data$string, "great"))
# or:
sum(grepl("great", q.data$string))
```

The two methods are perfect I think !

**But if there are many cells which contain many different specific strings, how to get all groups simutaneously.
Who has an efficienty method?**

A basal method is to do like this:

```
data<-data.frame(AA=sum(str_count(q.data$string, "utr")),
BB=sum(str_count(q.data$string, "DISTAL")),
CC=sum(str_count(q.data$string, "LONG")))
```

It will waste much time if there are more than 10 groups?

Comment: In your first code block, both `sum(..)` expressions return 0, but I think you're hoping to return the number of strings that contain `"great"` _twice_ (i.e., `3000`?). In your second block, it's not clear what `AA`, `BB`, `CC` mean and how it should be applied with/instead-of the first block. Please include the expected output.

Comment: You can search for something like "DISTAL|LONG".  However your final approach is still a good approach.

Comment: @r2evans , sorry, I print "great" twice by mistake. Yes, you know what I mean. And in the end, I want to gather all results and save them in a data frame. Here I  used different columns (AA, BB, CC or more) to save different group results.

Answer (score 0):

I find a perfect method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125474/count-multiple-patterns-using-the-str-count-function-in-r/76668504#76668504)

The answer from @akrun satisfied what I need.

It can get all results simutaneously.

Here is my code after modification based on The answer from @akrun

```
library(stringr)

q.data<-data.frame(number=1:3, string=c("great_utr_great", "ma_DISTAL_gic", "n_LONG_ot"))
q.data<-q.data[rep(1:NROW(q.data), 3000),]
 
vec1 <- c("utr","DISTAL","LONG")

## sapply(vec1, function(x) str_count(q.data$string,x))

Result<-data.frame(Group=sapply(unique(vec1), function(x) sum(str_count(q.data$string,x))))
Result
```

Answer (score -1):

we can try `str_detect` from `stringr` which is similar to `grepl`

```r
sum(str_detect(q.data$string, "greatgreat"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I know how to use it. But I want to get all results simutaneously and put them in a dataframe.   So I used a method in low efficiency.  You can see my code above.